# switch/case doesn't work in awk

Tags: linux, awk

I am writing a simple awk in redhat linux,but found switch/case doesn't work for me. I searched on web, but didn't find a solution. The following is my code:

```
 BEGIN {
   foo = 1;
     switch (foo) {
         case 3:
         print "x";
         break;
         case 2:
         print "y" ;
         break;
         case 1:
         print "z" ;
         break;
         default:
         print "default" ;
      }
 }
```

the awk I am running is GNU Awk 3.1.5. I got the following err:

> awk -f test.awk

```
awk: test.awk:3:      switch (foo) {
awk: test.awk:3:                   ^ syntax error
awk: test.awk:5:          case 3:
awk: test.awk:5:                ^ syntax error
awk: test.awk:8:          case 2:
awk: test.awk:8:                ^ syntax error
awk: test.awk:11:          case 1:
awk: test.awk:11:                ^ syntax error
awk: test.awk:14:          default:
awk: test.awk:14:                 ^ syntax error
```

can anybody please help me out? thank you!

Answer (score 14):

The GAWK manual says:

> #### 6.4.5 The switch Statement
>
> NOTE: This subsection describes an experimental feature added in gawk 3.1.3.
>   It is not enabled by default. To enable it, use the ‘--enable-switch’ option
>   to configure when gawk is being configured and built. See Section B.2.2 [Additional
>   Configuration Options], page 269, for more information.
>
> The switch statement allows the evaluation of an expression and the execution of statements
>   based on a case match. Case statements are checked for a match in the order they
>   are defined. If no suitable case is found, the default section is executed, if supplied.

Which version of `gawk` are you using?  Was it compiled with the `--enable-switch` option?

If you can't tell whether `gawk` was compiled with `--enable-switch` and you are getting syntax errors, it is reasonable to infer that it is not.  I'm using `gawk 3.1.8` compiled with the default configuration and get pretty much exactly the errors you are seeing on your script.  Given that, it is highly unlikely that your version is compiled with the necessary configuration option.  It isn't hard to recompile `gawk` with the option if you want to.

Comment: Thanks! my gawk version is gawk, version 3.1.5. But how do I know if it's compiled with --enable-switch option?

Comment: If you're getting syntax errors when trying to use the switch statement, it probably is *not* compiled with `--enable-switch` :)

Comment: I have gawk 4.0.1 on my system. The code in the question runs with no diagnostic messages and correctly prints `z`. The current [gawk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Switch-Statement.html) doesn't say the feature is experimental; it just says "This switch statement is a gawk extension. If gawk is in compatibility mode (see Options), it is not available."