# Errors when executing switch/case in awk command in Ubuntu and Mac

Tags: bash, awk, mawk

I have a very strange problem when executing following code:

```
awk '{ foo = 1; switch (foo) { case 1: i=i+1; break; } }' ./tcpheader.txt
```

Getting following error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    { foo = 1; switch (foo) >>>  { <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

Any idea what's the problem ?

*Tested on Mac:*

```
awk --version
```

Output:

```
awk version 20070501
```

*Tested on Ubuntu:*

```
awk -W version
```

Output:

```
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040
```

Comment: Please add name and version of your awk to your question. [The switch statement is a gawk-specific feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Switch-Statement).

Comment: @Cyrus I added the versions info.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401979/switch-case-doesnt-work-in-awk

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish I saw it, --enable-switch didn't help.

Comment: I think I have to install gawk instead of default awk ubuntu and mac awk version ...

Comment: Its not only about mawk, in mac I use something else...its about awk command in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing gawk solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install gawk
```

in mac:

```
sudo port install gawk
```

Comment: right, `switch` is a gawk extension as clearly stated in the documentation http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Switch-Statement