# How to use --enable-switch in a bash script having AWK statement

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gawk

Just found out that my problem using a switch-case in "awk" is exactly same as in this knowledge base:

[switch/case doesn't work in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401979/switch-case-doesnt-work-in-awk)

Now I'm using my awk statement in a bash script and not running it as a separate AWK script file. Considering that how can I use `--enable-switch` in my bash script. This is the structure of my script:

```
#! bin/ksh
. ~/.profile
// bash if-else statements to perform some tasks
/usr/bin/awk '
BEGIN {
        // array[] defined
}

// some statements
function printmsg(msg) {
         switch(1) {
         case /pattern1/:
              print msg
              break
         case /pattern2/:
              print msg
              break
         }
}' file
```

Where can I enforce `--enable-switch` ?

My GAWK version is `gawk-3.1.5-16.el5`

Comment: I think you are right. So only option I've right now is to change them into couple of if-else statements  :)

Comment: Based on my interpretation of the gawk man page for 3.1.7 the `--enable-switch` option is a compile time option and not a run time command line option unless it was first compiled with the `--enable-switch` option. I have version versions 4.1.3 installed and `switch` is a valid _control statement_ and requires nothing to use it. So, if the  `--enable-switch` option doesn't work I believe you either need to use a later version in which `switch` is compiled into the executable or you'll need to acquire the source code of the version you're using and compile it using the `--enable-switch` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an extremely old version of gawk, switch statements were enabled by default as of 4.0 and we're now on 4.1.something. You're missing a LOT of extremely useful functionality (much more useful than a switch statement, see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History) so get a new gawk.

Having said that, you could keep using switch() after installing a new gawk but IMHO that's just not worth making your script gawk-specific for, just rewrite it as if-elses if that's the only gawk-specific feature you're using.

Comment: Yes changed them to a set of if-else. The RHEL version running on lot of our systems is 5.x and all of them have gawk lesser than 4.x, so no point keeping the script gawk specific