# AWK - Processing multiple file through for loop and conditional check

Tags: bash, awk

File 1: myfilename_WEEK.csv

```
w27_2018,257,1,26.20,0.00,24.26
w28_2018,257,1,7.97,0.00,24.26
w29_2018,257,1,34.86,0.00,24.26
w30_2018,257,1,3.29,0.00,24.26
```

File 2: myfilename_MONTH.csv

```
m07_2018,257,1,94.78,0.00,121.31
m08_2018,257,1,719.60,0.00,262.47
m09_2018,257,1,14925.60,0.00,13903.24
m10_2018,257,1,51099.66,0.00,81600.69
```

File 3: myfilename_HALF.csv

```
h02_2018,257,1,155345.19,480029.21,235802.91
h01_2019,257,1,273961.84,552545.36,140706.27
h02_2018,258,1,3250552.06,1299785.91,3697749.57
h01_2019,258,1,3582585.66,2670427.72,4009391.28
```

calendar_file:

```
20180805,08/05/2018,w27_2018,WK27 2018,m07_2018,AUG 2018,q03_2018,Q03 2018,h02_2018,H02 2018,a2018,FY2018,27,WEEK 27,01,SUNDAY
20180806,08/06/2018,w27_2018,WK27 2018,m07_2018,AUG 2018,q03_2018,Q03 2018,h02_2018,H02 2018,a2018,FY2018,27,WEEK 27,02,MONDAY
...
20180811,08/11/2018,w27_2018,WK27 2018,m07_2018,AUG 2018,q03_2018,Q03 2018,h02_2018,H02 2018,a2018,FY2018,27,WEEK 27,07,SATURDAY
20180812,08/12/2018,w28_2018,WK28 2018,m07_2018,AUG 2018,q03_2018,Q03 2018,h02_2018,H02 2018,a2018,FY2018,28,WEEK 28,01,SUNDAY
..
20180816,08/16/2018,w28_2018,WK28 2018,m07_2018,AUG 2018,q03_2018,Q03 2018,h02_2018,H02 2018,a2018,FY2018,28,WEEK 28,05,THURSDAY
```

Expected output (newlines added for readability):

```
2018,w27_2018,WK27 2018,257,1,26.20,0.00,24.26
2018,w27_2018,WK27 2018,258,1,97192.07,9028.38,52130.32
2018,w27_2018,WK27 2018,300,1,181.44,0.00,-69.72

2018,m07_2018,AUG 2018,257,1,94.78,0.00,121.31
2018,m07_2018,AUG 2018,258,1,509253.46,45141.91,399648.71
2018,m07_2018,AUG 2018,300,1,409.10,0.00,-348.60

2018,h02_2018,H02 2018,257,1,155345.19,480029.21,235802.91
2018,h02_2018,H02 2018,258,1,3250552.06,1299785.91,3697749.57
2018,h02_2018,H02 2018,300,1,1112.93,0.00,-1164.35
```

I would like to join all `myfilename_*` to add a label and Fiscal Year using `calendar_file`:

Individual commands are:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$3]=substr($12,3,4) FS $3 FS $4; next} {print a[$1] FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6}' calendar_file myfilename_WEEK.csv >> my_report.csv

awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$5]=substr($12,3,4) FS $5 FS $6; next} {print a[$1] FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6}' calendar_file myfilename_MONTH.csv >> my_report.csv

awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$9]=substr($12,3,4) FS $9 FS $10; next} {print a[$1] FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6}' calendar_file myfilename_HALF.csv >> my_report.csv
```

I am trying to join all of these into a single loop:

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
    for exp_file in `ls myfilename_*.csv`
     do
     awk -F, '\
     { \
        if(NR==FNR && FILENAME ~ /WEEK/) {a[$3]=substr($12,3,4) FS $3 FS $4; next} ;\
        if(NR==FNR && FILENAME ~ /MONTH/) {a[$5]=substr($12,3,4) FS $5 FS $6; next} ;\
        if(NR==FNR && FILENAME ~ /HALF/) {a[$9]=substr($12,3,4) FS $9 FS $10; next} ;\
       {print a[$1] FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6} \
     }' calendar_file $exp_file >> my_report.csv
     done
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: @Tiw Thanks for editing. I have added expected output to my question.

Comment: Shell feedback: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. AWK feedback: you don't need to escape the newlines in your awk script, nor do you need to end lines with `;`, and you should use `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} ... {print a[1], $2, $3, ...}` so you're just using `OFS` as intended instead of writing `FS` between output fields (assuming you actually need to list output fields rather than just doing `{$1=a[$1]; print}`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Firt way**(GNU awk, if you don't have GNU awk please leave comment):

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{y=substr($12,3,4); a[$3]=y FS $3 FS $4; b[$5]=y FS $5 FS $6; c[$9]=y FS $9 FS $10; next} FNR==1{printf nl;nl="\n"} match(FILENAME, /myfilename_([A-Z]*)/, f){NF=6;switch(f[1]){case "WEEK": $1=a[$1];break; case "MONTH": $1=b[$1];break; case "HALF": $1=c[$1];}}1' OFS=, calendar_file myfilename_{WEEK,MONTH,HALF}.csv
```

Multiple lines for readability:

```
awk -F, '
NR==FNR{
    y=substr($12,3,4); 
    a[$3]=y FS $3 FS $4; 
    b[$5]=y FS $5 FS $6; 
    c[$9]=y FS $9 FS $10; 
    next
} 
FNR==1{printf nl;nl=ORS} ## The newlines between sectors, if you do not need those newlines then remove this line.
match(FILENAME, /myfilename_([A-Z]*)/, f){
    NF=6;  ## To limit results for 6 columns only, can remove it here.
    switch(f[1]){
    case "WEEK": 
        $1=a[$1];
        break; 
    case "MONTH": 
        $1=b[$1];
        break; 
    case "HALF": 
        $1=c[$1];
    }
}1' OFS=, calendar_file myfilename_{WEEK,MONTH,HALF}.csv
```

An update to it:

```
awk -F, '
NR==FNR{
    y=substr($12,3,4); 
    a[$3]=y FS $3 FS $4; 
    b[$5]=y FS $5 FS $6; 
    c[$9]=y FS $9 FS $10; 
    next
} 
FNR==1{printf nl;nl=ORS} ## The newlines between sectors, if you do not need those newlines then remove this line.
match(FILENAME, /myfilename_([A-Z]*)/, f){
    NF=6;  ## To limit results for 6 columns only, can remove in your case.
    $1 = f[1]=="WEEK" ? a[$1] : ( f[1]=="MONTH" ? b[$1] : (f[1]=="HALF" ? c[$1] : $1) )
}1' OFS=, calendar_file myfilename_{WEEK,MONTH,HALF}.csv
```

**Second Way**, more concise and without using `switch` (also GNU awk):

```
awk -F, '
NR==FNR{
    y=substr($12,3,4); 
    a[$3 "WEEK"]=y FS $3 FS $4; 
    a[$5 "MONTH"]=y FS $5 FS $6; 
    a[$9 "HALF"]=y FS $9 FS $10; 
    next
} 
FNR==1{printf nl;nl=ORS} ## The newlines between sectors, if you do not need those newlines then remove this line.
match(FILENAME, /myfilename_([A-Z]*)/, f){
    $1=a[$1 f[1]];
}1' OFS=, calendar_file myfilename_{WEEK,MONTH,HALF}.csv
```

**Third way**: If your data are all corresponding to their filenames, like you showed in your samples, there's a third way which removes the need of `match`, so it can work on other `awk`s:

```
awk -F, '
NR==FNR{
    y=substr($12,3,4); 
    a[$3 "w"]=y FS $3 FS $4; 
    a[$5 "m"]=y FS $5 FS $6; 
    a[$9 "h"]=y FS $9 FS $10; 
    next
} 
FNR==1{printf nl;nl=ORS} ## The newlines between sectors, if you do not need those newlines then remove this line.
$1~/^([wmh])[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4}/{   ## Check first fields to make sure it matches, the checking is optional if your data is all like you showed.
    $1=a[$1 substr($1,1,1)]
    print
}' OFS=, calendar_file myfilename_{WEEK,MONTH,HALF}.csv
```

Given a second thought, based on your data-filename relations, there's actually no need to check the first letter (nor the filename):

```
awk -F, '
NR==FNR{
    y=substr($12,3,4); 
    a[$3]=y FS $3 FS $4; 
    a[$5]=y FS $5 FS $6; 
    a[$9]=y FS $9 FS $10; 
    next
} 
FNR==1{printf nl;nl=ORS} ## The newlines between sectors, if you do not need those newlines then remove this line.
{   ## Add  $1~/^([wmh])[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4}/  to the beginning of this line if  you want to check and make sure first column.
    $1=a[$1]
}1' OFS=, calendar_file myfilename_{WEEK,MONTH,HALF}.csv
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tiw! As @oguzismail has mentioned, I have dropped NF=6. I understood the logic but struggled to execute it since my GNU Awk 3.1.7 on Linux was throwing "syntax error" after switch statement. After trying to fix it for an hour and failing, I found, through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401979/switch-case-doesnt-work-in-awk) , that the switch is not enabled by default and it has to be enabled using '--enable-switch' while compiling. Therefore, I had to replace switch with "if", as follows.

Comment: Final Answer: 
    awk -F, 'NR==FNR {y=substr($12,3,4); a[$3]=y FS $3 FS $4; b[$5]=y FS $5 FS $6; c[$9]=y FS $9 FS $10; next} 
match(FILENAME, /myfilename_([A-Z]*)/, f) {if(f[1]=="WEEK") $1=a[$1]; else if(f[1]=="MONTH") $1=b[$1]; else if (f[1]=="HALF") $1=c[$1];} 1' OFS=, calendar_file myfilename_{WEEK,MONTH,HALF}.csv >> my_report.csv

Comment: Thanks again! This gives me an idea to improve my script, for the report that I am working on. I was using multiple awk statements for each set of files and thought there must be a better way to do it.

Comment: That one is duplicating the records by printing both the original/input as well as output records. I am trying to figure it out.

Comment: @Tiw the second one will not work with all awks because 3rd argument to `match` is a GNU extension.

Comment: Yeah, checking the 3rd way. It's not giving any results. looks like something to do with the regex. checking on that

Comment: The digit repeaters in the regex were the problem. Need to check more on that. Just reduced the regex comparison to " $1~/^[wmh][0-9]/ " and it is working fine. And yes, the field is always one of those and it works even without the regex match. Thanks to you and @orguzimail !!!

Comment: @acs005 Great. Also check the content I updated :)   The repeater might not working on your version or something. However I'm feeling it's strange. Btw, what system and version are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle Linux Server release 6.10

Comment: @acs005 Guess that's why those different behaviors. I mainly testing on GNU Awk 4.1.4, don't have Oracle Linux to test on now.  Just made an updated to the first way and it's actually a variation to your if else change, I guess this is my final update on this answer now. Happy learning, cya :)

Comment: Thanks for editing the answers neatly so that it's clear and useful to others as well. Yeah, a lot to learn! This will be my final comment as well. Cya :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is another awk solution which is portable, efficient and doesn't rely on input filenames but the order they are given on command line.

```sh
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '
NR==FNR {
  y=substr($12,3,4)
  a[ARGV[2],$3]=y OFS $3 OFS $4  # week
  a[ARGV[3],$5]=y OFS $5 OFS $6  # month
  a[ARGV[4],$9]=y OFS $9 OFS $10 # half
  next
}
{
  $1=a[FILENAME,$1]
} 1' calendar.csv week.csv month.csv half.csv
```

Note that if your calendar file is sorted, there is no need to parse fiscal year field again and again for each line. Something like this would be way more efficient in that case:

```
if(p!=$12) y=substr(p=$12,3,4)
```

Comment: This also worked like a charm! Thank you! Yes, the calendar file is always sorted and hence I used your recommendation to avoid parsing the fiscal year again and again.